# Convert route path parameters into an array in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In my node app I want to route and indefinite number of paths in a url to one template, and then present to that template an array of all the paths.

For example, I want to allow the routes `'/'`,`/foo/`,`/foo/bar/` and `/foo/bar/[...etc]` all to point to the same view template with the paths split into an array, ie: `[]`, `['foo']`, `['foo','bar']`, respectively.

This code, seems to answer the first part of the question:

```
app.route('/*')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.render('index',{
        paths: req.params[0]
    });
  });
```

But when I loop through the `paths` variable in my template, each letter is out put individually rather than path by path.

Is this possible? And if so, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're looping through a string so it's pulling each character from that string. Just change `req.params[0]` to `req.params[0].split('/')`.

`http://localhost:4000/my/full/path` will give you `[ 'my', 'full', 'path' ]` as the `paths` variable in your view.

Comment: I was pretty convinced I'd tried this and it threw an error (req.params[0] has no method "split" but I must have been entering wrong. Your way's working though so thanks a lot!

Comment: No probs! Good luck with your project.